# Trouble finding file path of Web Services not in inetpub\wwwroot on Remote PC C#

Tags: c#, web-services, iis-7

I am trying to find the file path to web services that are not hosted in the normal Inetpub\wwwroot.  I am wanting to find the version of the web services to check to make sure 2 PC have the same version which I have done now so long as I spiffy the exact file path or the web services are held in the normal spot.  Unfortunately I have some PC that have the web services in multiple location so specifying the file path is not really possible.  I can see that this type of question has been asked before([Get .svc file info of IIS web service on remote computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491198/get-svc-file-info-of-iis-web-service-on-remote-computer)) but I cannot find answers to those questions.

Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**:  It is probable that what I am trying to do is actually not possible without having something on the target PC(an extra web method or a service or secondary app to pull the info).  If that is the case that is fine, I am thinking about making to user point to the directory that has the web services on the remote PC which will work if it is very clunky for PCs with the web services in multiple directories.

**Edit2**:  I have found a few more things that I feel like are getting me closer.  What I have now is:

```
      string path = "IIS://ServernameorIP/W3SVC";
      DirectoryEntry w3svc = new DirectoryEntry(path, AdministratorUser, AdministratorUserPassword, 0);
      w3svc.RefreshCache();//not sure if this is needed
      foreach (DirectoryEntry entry in w3svc.Children)
            {
                  //do some stuff to get the paths
            }
```

This gets me some information, messing with the path gets me the sites I am looking for.  I am not sure how still how to pull the physical path however.  I am also having problems with the impersonation on the DirectoryEntry.  I give it an administrator user and password and it still seems to send my local user and password as evidenced by the fact that those lines did not work until I added my user and password to the remote PC.  Any help on either of those two would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: in future you can have service method to return `System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath` then you can find the location

Comment: Damith,  The only problem is adding that in my environment is not really a possibility(as good of an idea as it is).  I am building this to find the version of the web services on two computers and compare them.  Adding something new(which is most of the time not possible) would render this useless.  Thanks for the tip for the future however.

Comment: I would say that having a service method that gave out the physical DLL location is probably an unsafe practice.  In your case, you need the version information.  Having a service method that provided the version information from your AssemblyInfo would be a better approach.  Since you can't change your deployments to add this information, I suggest fetching the WSDL from both computers and manually comparing them (like with [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) a great file comparison utility). That's a bit of P.I.T.A. but it should show you in excruciating detail what different.

Comment: @Dave, thanks for the info I just tried that but the WSDL does not contain any direct file path information only virtual directories. And I cant compare the information in the WSDL as the arguments and method names are not necessarily all that will change in the web service.  I still think I need something that will give me the actual directory and the I can pull the version number from a dll.  Thanks for the info though, I might be able to use it in a different app.

Comment: If you have access to IIS on the machine, just find the site/vdir, right click on it, and hit Explore.

Comment: @zimdanen I am trying to do this programmatically so that I have an answer for any PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I have found where this information is stored.  I have to use windows rather than IIS to give me the answer but I will be impersonating a local or domain administrator for use in this this app on the remote computer so it is not an issue for me in this case.

The ApplicationHost.Config file actually has the informaton that I need in the format:

```
<application path="/WebService_SomeWebService" applicationPool="DefaultAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebService_SomeWebService" />
            </application>
            <application path="/WebService_SomeOtherWebService" applicationPool="DefaultAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\SomeotherFilepath\WebService_SomeOtherWebService" />
            </application>
```

All I need to do is to pull that file from %windir%\System32\inetsrv\config and parse out the info that I need.  Thanks to everyone who helped.